# Swift code problem - trying to cast objects out from a NSMutableArray as a custom object

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

Here is my code and it fails to execute as noted below.

I am trying to cast an object to my custom data type called UserData. 
First problem I have is don't understand how to get the value out of the array correctly
Second I cannot seem to cast the object as the type I need, UserData. What I am doing wrong?

```
    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()
        var users = NSMutableArray();

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count {

            print("loop count :", i );

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let user = UserData()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let UserID = jsonElement["Userid"] as? String,
                let firstName = jsonElement["First_Name"] as? String,
                let lastName = jsonElement["Last_Name"] as? String,
                let userSessionID = jsonElement["Session_ID"] as? String
            {

                user.UserID = UserID
                user.FirstName = firstName
                user.LastName = lastName
                user.UserSessionID = userSessionID

                print("users firstName:", user.FirstName ?? "blank");

            }

            users.add(user)
        }

        print("users size:", users.count); // this shows 2 
        // So i know I have data loaded... BUT when i try and 
        // get it then it all goes to heck. See below


        // NOT SURE what I am doing here...
        // Thought it was java like where I could just get a
        // item from the NSMutableArray using an index value
        // then cast it as my UserData object
        // and print the output... but this does not work 
        // Why is this so hard?? 

        let userDataVal = users.index(of: 0) as! UserData;
        print("firstName:", userDataVal.FirstName);

    }
```

Comment: Don't use NSArray (or any other NS collection class), use the Swift type `Array` instead.

Comment: like above comment says: unless you are explicitly getting an error that asks you to use NS*, or dealing with code interpolation between swift and objc, don't use NS* objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better approach would be to use JSONDecoder() instead of a JSONSerailizer. Try using the following code.

```
struct User: Codable {
    var userId, firstName, lastName, userSessionId: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userId = "Userid"
        case firstName = "First_Name"
        case lastName = "Last_Name"
        case userSessionId = "Session_ID"
    }
}

func parseJSON(_ data: Data) {
    do {
        let users = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
        users.forEach { user in
            print("users first name:", user.firstName)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I would write this function. Some comments

- No NS... classes used, instead I use native arrays and dictionaries
- If JSONSerialization.jsonObject generates an error the function is exited
- Local variables are define as close as possible to as where they are used
- Create an init method for your `UserData` struct/class that takes the values as parameters so you can do `let user = UserData(userId: UserId, firstName:...` instead.
- Name local variables and properties with a first lowercase character, it makes it easier to read the code

---

```
func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {
    var jsonResult: [[String: Any]]?
    do {
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    guard let result = jsonResult else {
        return
    }

    var users = [UserData]()
    for jsonElement in result {
        if let UserID = jsonElement["Userid"] as? String,
            let firstName = jsonElement["First_Name"] as? String,
            let lastName = jsonElement["Last_Name"] as? String,
            let userSessionID = jsonElement["Session_ID"] as? String
        {
            var user = UserData()
            user.UserID = UserID
            user.FirstName = firstName
            user.LastName = lastName
            user.UserSessionID = userSessionID
            users.append(user)
        }
    }

    for user in users {
        print("firstName:", user.FirstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: The parse function worked...but how would i loop through the rest of the objects in the users array?

Comment: @user1260085 See my edit. But the best thing would probably be to return the array from the function and do the looping outside